# mkbundle does not find dependencies from current directory

Tags: .net, linux, mono, mkbundle

I am trying to create a bundle for my .net application using Mono on Linux. when I execute the mkbundle command as below -

```
$>mkbundle -o ConsoleApp ConsoleApp.exe  --deps
    OS is: Linux
    Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
    Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'sharedassembly' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'sharedassembly'
```

However, sharedassembly.dll is present in current directory. how to tell mkbundle that load the file from current directory.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 3):

Try to explicitly add `sharedassembly.dll` to your mkbundle command:

```
mkbundle -o ConsoleApp ConsoleApp.exe sharedassembly.dll --deps
```

Comment: Wildcards work too: mkbundle -o ConsoleApp ConsoleApp.exe *.dll --deps